Putting logger generated logs in RobotFramework report
I am aware that robot framework provides a logger. However, I dont want to duplicate the efforts of putting logger messages in my python code as well as robot framework. (More than "I dont want to", I am affraid that I may not remember to update both of them if I make any changes.)
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

def func1():
logging.info("Simple log message")

Is there a way that I can redirect this message to report.html?
I searched internet for any inputs. But I could not get any relevant answers.

messages logged via logging module in python code from within current python interpreter are included in robot's report files.
